# Removing ValueEventListener from each RecyclerView object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

I have a RecyclerView populated by some CardView with a picture some TextView and a Button (with works as a "like" button). I'm using Transaction to update some simple counters, but before liking/unliking i have to check if the UserId is present in a node of my Database like :

```
 Post_reference :
                 ----userId_1_String: someValue
                 ----userId_2_String: someValue
                 ----userId_3_String: someValue
```

If the userId is present i want to remove it and then update the counters(at a different node) with a Transaction, else i want to add it and then update the counters.
The main problem is that i basically just need to check this once and then i want to remove the listener to avoid memory leaks but i can't find a way to make it work. I've been using AddValueListenerForSingleValueEvent but it's even worse since you can't detach it

Comment: You can achieve this with the snipped method that I posted you below. Also you should implement an interface with a method called `toogleLike()` or something like that and pass the listener from your `Activity` to your `RecyclerView`. Doing that you can set an `onClickListener` in each `RecyclerView` item with their current position.

Comment: That's not exactly what i asked, also i don't see where in the snippet the listener is removed. Your post basically just add and remove some value at a reference, what i'm looking for is to check if the like is present or not, then do a transaction and then remove the listener right after that. This listener will bee attached on each element in the recyclerView and if the user likes (as an example), 100 different post i need to remove 100 different listeners and i'm looking for a way to do that just after the Like method finishes is job to avoid memory leaks

Comment: Why you want to attach 100 different listeners? Just use `onChildEventListener`, which will notify you of every new, changed, deleted, or moved children in your databaseReference with a single listener: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener

Answer (score 1):

Solved this, it was pretty easy but it might help someone in the future.
Say you have a reference to you database called ref :

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ValueEventListener yourValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //your code on datasnapshot
                    ref.removeEventListener(this);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            };
            ref.addValueEventListener(yourValueEventListener);
        }
    });
```

This basically reads/writes on the node and immediately detach the listener

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you should remove the value from your `Post_reference` when you unlike it.

The case is that if I like your post I should have a reference for your `postID` to my `userID`, and if I didn't like your post I should have nothing. So, you can always check your transactions with `dataSnapshop.exists()`.

```
@Override
public void onPostLike(final String postKey) {
    final String userKey = FirebaseUtil.getCurrentUserId();
    final DatabaseReference postLikesRef = FirebaseUtil.getLikesRef();
    postLikesRef.child(postKey).child(userKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                // User already liked this post, so we toggle like off.
                postLikesRef.child(postKey).child(userKey).removeValue();
            } else {
                postLikesRef.child(postKey).child(userKey).setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

You can find a fully functional example for the same case that you are describing in the [Friendlypix](https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix/tree/master/android) Firebase example, which simulates a kind of social media where you can follow people and see their posts.